# How to Dynamically Position Widgets in a SingleChildScrollView and Animate Between Positions in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm currently working on a Flutter project where I have a stack of widgets inside a SingleChildScrollView. The positions of these widgets are retrieved from existing widgets, and since they are within a SingleChildScrollView, the positions can dynamically change as the user scrolls.

I've created a simplified version of my widget hierarchy where I have a red container, a blue container, and a green container that should overlap either the red or blue container based on certain conditions. I'm using AnimatedPositioned for the animation effect.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool move = false;

  final GlobalKey redContainerKey = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey blueContainerKey = GlobalKey();

  double? _topPosition;

  // Position of Strings
  Offset _getWidgetPosition(GlobalKey key) {
    RenderBox renderBox = key.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    return renderBox.localToGlobal(const Offset(0, 0));
  }

  void _getPosition() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      double topPosition = move
          ? _getWidgetPosition(redContainerKey).dy
          : _getWidgetPosition(blueContainerKey).dy;

      setState(() {
        _topPosition = topPosition;
      });

      print(topPosition);
    });
  }

  final _scrollController = ScrollController();

  // Scroll to Top
  void _scrollToTop() {
    _scrollController.animateTo(
      0.0,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      curve: Curves.linear,
    );
  }

  // Scroll to Bottom
  void _scrollToBottom() {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
      _scrollController.animateTo(
        _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        curve: Curves.linear,
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  key: redContainerKey,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  height: 50,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                ),
                Container(height: 700),
                Container(
                  key: blueContainerKey,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  height: 50,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            AnimatedPositioned(
              top: _topPosition,
              duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
              child: AnimatedContainer(
                duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                color: Colors.green,
                height: 50,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            move = !move;
            if (move) {
              _scrollToTop();
            } else {
              _scrollToBottom();
            }
            _getPosition();
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

While this works, the issue is that the green container doesn't always overlap the red or blue container as expected, especially when the screen is moving due to scrolling. I'm looking for guidance on how to achieve this dynamic positioning and animation effect seamlessly in a SingleChildScrollView. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. Introduce Keys: I addressed the issue by assigning unique keys to the widgets in the stack. This step was crucial for referencing their positions dynamically.
2. Calculate Precise Position: To achieve seamless positioning, I calculated the precise position by subtracting the current y position of the stack from the y position of the destination widget. It's essential to account for factors like the height of the AppBar.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  // Global Key
  final GlobalKey stackKey = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey redContainerKey = GlobalKey();
  final GlobalKey blueContainerKey = GlobalKey();

  // Flag to Indicate Type of Movement
  bool move = false;

  // Position (y) for Animated Positioned
  double? _topPosition;

  // Position of Widget
  Offset _getWidgetPosition(GlobalKey key) {
    RenderBox renderBox = key.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    return renderBox
        .localToGlobal(const Offset(0, -80)); // Account for AppBar height
  }

  // Retrieving Position of Widget
  void _getPosition() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      double topPosition = move
          ? _getWidgetPosition(redContainerKey).dy
          : (_getWidgetPosition(blueContainerKey).dy -
              _getWidgetPosition(stackKey).dy);

      setState(() {
        _topPosition = topPosition;
      });
    });
  }

  // Scroll Controller
  final _scrollController = ScrollController();

  // Scroll to Top
  void _scrollToTop() {
    _scrollController.animateTo(
      0.0,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
      curve: Curves.linear,
    );
  }

  // Scroll to Bottom
  void _scrollToBottom() {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
      _scrollController.animateTo(
        _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        curve: Curves.linear,
      );
    });
  }

  // Scroll Notification
  bool handleScrollNotification(ScrollNotification notification) {
    if (notification is ScrollEndNotification) {
      _getPosition();
    }
    return true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
        onNotification: handleScrollNotification,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          child: Stack(
            key: stackKey,
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    key: redContainerKey,
                    color: Colors.red,
                    height: 50,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  ),
                  Container(height: 1000), // Change this to observe desired behaviour
                  Container(
                    key: blueContainerKey,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    height: 50,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              AnimatedPositioned(
                top: _topPosition,
                duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                child: AnimatedContainer(
                  duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                  color: Colors.green,
                  height: 50,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            move = !move;
          });
          if (move) {
            _scrollToTop();
          } else {
            _scrollToBottom();
          }
          _getPosition();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```